# Determine padding for correctly placing a Button in the top-trailing corner?

Tags: swiftui

In an application that hides the status bar, is there something in SwiftUI that helps with correctly placing a button in the top-trailing corner?

[image]

The padding necessary for it to look correct seems dependent on the device type (with or without notch / "corner radius" of the display varying with the device size). There will be no safe area insets on the top with the status bar hidden.

How can the correct padding for such a button be determined? Is there a better way than to check for specific device types / screen sizes?

Example code:

```swift
// SwiftUIPlayground
// https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CloseButtonExampleView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay(self.closeButton, alignment: .topTrailing)
    }

    @ViewBuilder var closeButton: some View {
        Button(
            action: {},
            label: {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        )
        .padding(16) // <-- what's the correct value?
    }

}

struct CloseButtonExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previewView: some View {
        CloseButtonExampleView()
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        previewView
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone SE (2nd generation)"))
        previewView
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 12"))
        previewView
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 12 Pro Max"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the correct is not hard code any value there at all, so just using

```
@ViewBuilder var closeButton: some View {
    Button(

       // .. other code here
    )
    .padding()         // << default !!
    .ignoresSafeArea() // << !!
}
```

gives (tested with Xcode 12.5 / iOS 14.5)

[image: demo1]

[image: demo2]

[image: demo3]